# I can't find Chop at my house

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I had to stop playing GTA V for a bit, then when I got on back I can't find my dog (Chop) at the house.

I think it might be due to the fact that I deleted the Chop app. Can I get him back without the app?

Comment: Which house are you in?

Comment: Could he be at your aunt's. I think I had that happen to me probably story related.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the app to have Chop. He should be near his kennel.